# \psrotate behaving differently under XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, pstricks

When compiling the following mwe with XeLaTeX, the \psrotate command doesn't have the intended effect of rotating 90 degrees. Compiling with LaTeX on the other hand works.

Is this a know issue or am I doing something wrong? In case it is a bug, where should I report it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{
    pstricks,
    pst-eucl,
    pstricks-add
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-2,-3.5)(2,3.5)
\newcommand{\f}[1]{#1 dup mul .1 \space mul 1 \space add}
\newcommand{\g}[1]{#1 dup mul .1 \space mul 1 \space add neg}

\psrotate(0,0){90}
{
\psplot{-3}{3}{\f{x}}
\psplot{-3}{3}{\g{x}}
\psellipse(3,0)(! .2 \f{3})
\psellipticarc(-3,0)(! .2 \f{-3}){90}{270}
\psellipse[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!60](-2,0)(! .2 \f{-2})
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!20]
{
\psplot{-3}{-2}{\f{x}}
\psellipticarc(-2,0)(! .2 \f{-2}){90}{270}
\psplot{-2}{-3}{\g{x}}
\psellipticarc(-3,0)(! .2 \f{-3}){90}{270}
}
\psline[linecolor=blue!20,linewidth=.9pt](! -3 \f{-3})(! -3 \g{-3})
} 
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I remember that @ArtificialSupidity and I once had a conversation on this, but I can't find the question any more, and the same problem arises when compiling [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350960/121799). (I realized the problem a long time after I posted it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the simple `\psrotatebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\psrotatebox{90}{%
  \begin{pspicture}(-2,-3.5)(2,3.5)
  \newcommand{\f}[1]{#1 dup mul .1 \space mul 1 \space add}
  \newcommand{\g}[1]{#1 dup mul .1 \space mul 1 \space add neg} 
  \psplot{-3}{3}{\f{x}}
  \psplot{-3}{3}{\g{x}}
  \psellipse(3,0)(! .2 \f{3})
  \psellipticarc(-3,0)(! .2 \f{-3}){90}{270}
  \psellipse[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!60](-2,0)(! .2 \f{-2})
  \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!20]
        {
            \psplot{-3}{-2}{\f{x}}
            \psellipticarc(-2,0)(! .2 \f{-2}){90}{270}
            \psplot{-2}{-3}{\g{x}}
            \psellipticarc(-3,0)(! .2 \f{-3}){90}{270}
        }
  \psline[linecolor=blue!20,linewidth=.9pt](! -3 \f{-3})(! -3 \g{-3})
\end{pspicture}%
}

\end{document}
```