# Styles in datavisualization legends

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-datavisualization

I have a bunch of plots in a datavisualization environment with different styles for each plot. When I collect them into a legend, they all show up in black. I've constructed a quick MWE based on an example in the manual

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \datavisualization data group {lines} = {
   data point [x=0, y=0, set=normal]
data point [x=2, y=2, set=normal]
data point [x=0, y=1, set=heated]
data point [x=2, y=1, set=heated]
data point [x=0.5, y=1.5, set=critical]
data point [x=2.25, y=1.75, set=critical]
                                };
  \datavisualization [
school book axes={unit=0.3},
visualize as line=normal,
visualize as line=heated,
visualize as line=critical,
normal={style={green}, label in legend={text={normal}}},
heated={style={yellow}, label in legend={text={heated}}},
critical={style={red}, label in legend={text={critical}}},
legend=north east inside]
  data group {lines};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Do I need to specify the colour information somewhere again? When using style sheets, the colours show up correctly in the legend but I would greatly prefer to set colours separately.

[image]

Comment: are you sure? Because, when I compiled your MWE, it works as you wanted. I see no problems.

Comment: Strange, I get the behaviour shown in the image. Can you tell me your TeX version?

Comment: MiKTex-2.9.6300 compiled with Texstudio 2.11.2. I hope that helps.

Comment: I confirm @RaajaG's statement with my TeXLive 2018 distribution. Wait! I do get the OP's output when compiling with `xelatex`, but with `pdflatex` and `lualatex` the colors show correctly. (I do not know if that is related, but it also happens with pstricks that `xelatex` sometimes fails to produce the correct result.)

Comment: I have TeXLive 2018 as well, Live Utility shows no available updates for tikz. Strange… Are there any other ways to set the colour of the legend labels?

Comment: What happens if you compile with `pdflatex` or `lualatex`?

Comment: @marmot I compiled with pdflatex --> no issues so far.

Comment: @RaajaG Yes, that is in agreement with my findings: only `xelatex` fails to produce the correct output. Could you please try `xelatex`?

Comment: Latex, Xelatex, Xetex all produce the same output for me, whether this is changed in the settings panel of Texlive or in the edit window.

Comment: A restart of the Texshop editor changed it. Still strange behaviour under Xelatex. Is this a bug I should file? The prior setting was on Xelatex.

Comment: @RaajaG Just to be absolutely certain: when you compile with `xelatex`, the legend curves are colored and *not* black (as in the OP's screen shot)?

Comment: @marmot for me `xelatex` does not produces the same output (I agree with you) --> sorry refersh issues --> legends are in BW.

Comment: Interestingly, if you add `style sheet=vary hue`, then some colors show even when compiled with `xelatex`, but these colors do not match. However, these colors do match when compiled with `pdflatex`. ...

Comment: After running a few tests with restarting TeXShop: All settings changed in  the "Preferences" -> "Typesetting" -> "Default command" panel. XeLaTeX produces black labels. LaTeX produces the correct output. Using `style sheet` does work, but I prefer having my own colours (for consistency across several graphs) and using XeLaTeX for typesetting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround, you could create a style sheet that uses the same colors as your lines. Then also `xelatex` creates a colorful legend.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}

\pgfdvdeclarestylesheet{Huang d}{
  1/.style={green!50!black},
  2/.style={yellow!90!black},
  3/.style={red!80!black},
  default style/.style={black}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \datavisualization data group {lines} = {
   data point [x=0, y=0, set=normal]
data point [x=2, y=2, set=normal]
data point [x=0, y=1, set=heated]
data point [x=2, y=1, set=heated]
data point [x=0.5, y=1.5, set=critical]
data point [x=2.25, y=1.75, set=critical]
                                };
  \datavisualization [
school book axes={unit=0.3},style sheet=Huang d,
visualize as line=normal,
visualize as line=heated,
visualize as line=critical,
normal={style={green}, label in legend={text={normal}}},
heated={style={yellow}, label in legend={text={heated}}},
critical={style={red}, label in legend={text={critical}}},
legend=north east inside]
  data group {lines};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A much simpler possibility is provided by [Huang_d's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/444316/121799), which can be further simplified to

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}

\pgfdvdeclarestylesheet{xelatex workaround}{
  default style/.style={black}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \datavisualization data group {lines} = {
   data point [x=0, y=0, set=normal]
data point [x=2, y=2, set=normal]
data point [x=0, y=1, set=heated]
data point [x=2, y=1, set=heated]
data point [x=0.5, y=1.5, set=critical]
data point [x=2.25, y=1.75, set=critical]
                                };
  \datavisualization [
school book axes={unit=0.3},style sheet=xelatex workaround,
visualize as line=normal,
visualize as line=heated,
visualize as line=critical,
normal={style={green}, label in legend={text={normal}}},
heated={style={yellow}, label in legend={text={heated}}},
critical={style={red}, label in legend={text={critical}}},
legend=north east inside]
  data group {lines};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives a universal output, i.e. same for `pdflatex`, `xelatex` and `lualatex`.

[image]

Comment: You are a wonderful marmot! Thank you very much! I guess I will have to take care of the order of plots now, but at least it works with all constraints.

Comment: @Huang_d Thanks, yes, that's just a workaround. There seems also an issue with `xelatex` in pstricks, see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/422218/121799). To the best of my knowledge, this has never been resolved. And I do not know if these issues are related, let alone how to fix them. But I am glad to hear that this workaround works for you. ;-)

Comment: Playing around with it, you actually still need the `normal={style={green}}` part, otherwise it is still black. This is some really funky cross-interaction. Setting the style sheet to all black and defining colours in the styles gives the/a desired behaviour, black text and correctly coloured lines.

Comment: @Huang_d I confirm your observation and am wondering if you want to post this better workaround as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be an interaction between Xe(La)TeX and Ti*k*Z. In order to get black text with correctly coloured labels, a black style sheet needs to be used. The colours can then be set as expected:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}

\pgfdvdeclarestylesheet{allblack}{default style/.style={black}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \datavisualization data group {lines} = {
   data point [x=0, y=0, set=normal]
data point [x=2, y=2, set=normal]
data point [x=0, y=1, set=heated]
data point [x=2, y=1, set=heated]
data point [x=0.5, y=1.5, set=critical]
data point [x=2.25, y=1.75, set=critical]
                                };
  \datavisualization [
school book axes={unit=0.3},style sheet=allblack,
visualize as line=normal,
visualize as line=heated,
visualize as line=critical,
normal={style={green}, label in legend={text={normal}}},
heated={style={yellow}, label in legend={text={heated}}},
critical={style={red}, label in legend={text={critical}}},
legend=north east inside]
  data group {lines};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This yields correctly coloured lines and black text. The text colour can be changed with the style sheet if necessary.

Comment: You can do it even shorter: `\pgfdvdeclarestylesheet{Huang d}{
  default style/.style={black}
}`.

Comment: I guess you want to either name the style `allblack` or use `style sheet=Huang d` in the plot. (I also appended that to my answer, of course giving credit to your answer.)