# Label in data color don't work in tikz environment

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to get a colored label for my plot (I use \datavisualization command, not \begin{axis} environment) but with no good results: my label (sinx) still remain black but I wpuld like to have it blue as the plot. I red the manual but I don't understand where I'm wrong, I did as the manual says... can someone help me?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\datavisualization [
  school book axes,
  visualize as smooth line=i, 
  x axis={label={$\omega t$},        
             grid,grid={style={dashed,draw opacity=1},step=1},
             ticks={{major at={
             0 as 0,
             1 as $\frac \pi 2$,
             2 as $\pi$,
             3 as []$\frac{3\pi} 2$,
             4 as $2\pi$
             }}}},
  y axis={ticks=none},
   i={style=blue,label in data={text=sinx, when=x is 1,
                    text colored}}]
data [format=function, set= i] {
  var x : interval [0:4] ;
  func y = sin(deg(\value x*pi*0.5 ));
};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Do you compile with `xelatex`? The reason I am asking this is [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/444301/121799).

Comment: I edit the post to make the code compilable. I normally use PDFLaTex to compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for providing a compilable example! If you add an appropriate style sheet, it works.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\datavisualization [
  school book axes,
  visualize as smooth line=i, 
  x axis={label={$\omega t$},        
             grid,grid={style={dashed,draw opacity=1},step=1},
             ticks={{major at={
             0 as 0,
             1 as $\frac \pi 2$,
             2 as $\pi$,
             3 as []$\frac{3\pi} 2$,
             4 as $2\pi$
             }}}},
  y axis={ticks=none},
  style sheet=vary hue,
   i={style=blue,label in data={text=$\sin x$, when=x is 1,text colored}}]
data [format=function, set=i] {
  var x : interval [0:4] ;
  func y = sin(deg(\value x*pi*0.5 ));
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As for your comment: honestly, the behavior here appears a bit odd to me. On can do green text as well, e.g. with

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
\tikzdvdeclarestylesheetcolorseries{greens}{hsb}{0.3,1.3,0.8}{0,-.4,-.1}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\datavisualization [
  school book axes,style sheet=greens,
  %style sheet=marco roberto,
  visualize as smooth line=i, 
  x axis={label={$\omega t$},        
             grid,grid={style={dashed,draw opacity=1},step=1},
             ticks={{major at={
             0 as 0,
             1 as $\frac \pi 2$,
             2 as $\pi$,
             3 as $\frac{3\pi} 2$,
             4 as $2\pi$
             }}}},
  y axis={ticks=none},
  i={label in data={text=$\sin x$, when=x is 1,text colored}}
  ]
data [format=function, set=i] {
  var x : interval [0:4] ;
  func y = sin(deg(\value x*pi*0.5 ));
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But I agree with you that this is more complicated than it should.

Comment: @marcoroberto94 Good point. I also do not know what's going on. Could be that you found a bug. I added something that does the green thingy but it is unnecessarily complicated.